# Get a list of all values in a model

Tags: python, django, list

I am trying to sanitize my database inputs in Django by verifying fields.  So I have a library model, that has as a field "type", which can be any value from a list.  My Library model declaration looks like this:

```
class Library(models.Model):
  library_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, db_index=True)
  library_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,help_text="NOT allowed chars: "+", ".join(ILLEGAL_CHARS))
  account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True)

  EXPERIMENT_TYPES = (
      ('Member1','Description Member1'),
      ('Member2', 'Description Member1'),
      ('Member3', 'Description Member1'),
      ('Member4', 'Description Member1'),
      ('Member5', 'Description Member1'),
      ('Member6', 'Description Member1'),
      ('Member7','Description Member1'),
  ) 
  experiment_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EXPERIMENT_TYPES, default='Member1')
```

What I need is if I have a value
    myType="Member90"
to be able to do a test to make sure that myType is in EXPERIMENT_TYPES

What I have right now is this, which sort of works.  But there should be a better way.

```
try:
    Library.objects.filter(experiment_type=myType)
except:
    library_errors.append("Json has invalid value \'%s\' in \'Experiment Type\' field. Experiment Type does not exist." % (myType))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check using your model static choices tuple instead of db:

```
if myType not in [e[0] for e in Library.EXPERIMENT_TYPES]:
    library_errors.append('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do is filter out the valid/expected results, leaving nothing but invalid results:

```
# Retrieve a list of valid values for experiment_type
valid_experiment_types = list(map(lambda x: x[0], Library.EXPERIMENT_TYPES))

# Now, exclude any valid experiment_type(s) from your QuerySet
invalid_objects = Library.objects.exclude(
    experiment_type__in=valid_experiment_types
)

# What you are left with is nothing but invalid values
#     Let's see what they are...
print(invalid_objects.values_list('experiment_type', flat=True))

"""
Sample Output:
['Member90', 'Member40']
"""

# Let's view all of the information available
print(invalid_objects.values())

"""
Sample Output:
[{'library_id': '12345', 'library_name': 'Test', 'account': 1123, 'experiment_type': 'Member90'}, {'library_id': '678', 'library_name': 'Neat', 'account': 5464, 'experiment_type': 'Member40'}]
"""
```

Once you have the invalid values, you can decide what to do with them. You are left with is a QuerySet, so you can easily view any of the values.

Continuing the above example, you can do:

```
# Set up the errors list
library_errors = []

# Loop through the invalid objects and add your error message
for obj_value in invalid_objects.values_list('experiment_type', flat=True):
    library_errors.append("Json has invalid value \'%s\' in \'Experiment Type\' field. Experiment Type does not exist." % (obj_value))
```

Best of luck!